# Can't solve VBScript type mismatch. It isn't a true mismatch

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic

Hi all I have the strangest type mismatch in my VB Script. I have no idea what to do.

I define my global variables up top.

Preamble:

```
Public intX, intY, firstX,firstY

intX = CInt(InputBox("Set X Coordinate above ONE in Excel to Start pasting"))
intY = CInt(InputBox("Set Y Coordinate above ONE in Excel to Start pasting"))

firstX = intX
firstY = intY
firstY = CInt(firstY)
```

I then have some code running here (note:firstY and firstX go untouched, they are treated as anchors, in a way). Then I have the below loop which adds rows based on the count of existing rows (intY becoming the delimiter for the loop) and certain arguments. firstY exists to help this loop retrace to the starting position of the excel sheet so it can work its way down.

```
Dim x, y, adder, i
adder=1
i=0
x=0
y=0
Do While x<intY
    If ws.Cells(firstY, IntX+3)+ws.Cells(firstY,IntX+5)>1 Then
    adder=ws.Cells(firstY, IntX+3)+ws.Cells(firstY,IntX+5)-1
        For i = 1 to adder
            ws.Cells(firstY+1,IntX).EntireRow.Insert
        Next

    End If
    firstY=firstY+adder+1
    adder=0
    x=x+1
Loop
```

I get the error Type mismatch: '[string: ""]' on line If ws.Cells(firstY, IntX+3)+ws.Cells... Then

Any ideas as to why this is occuring?

When I print the types they actually look OK (all int, but eventually firstY becomes type double as the loop keeps going)

```
'   MsgBox TypeName(firstY) &" " & TypeName(x) &" " & TypeName(intY)
```

I'm sorry if I come off like a coding cretin but I really don't know what to do here.

Any help in troubleshooting is appreciated.

Comment: Probably because `adder=ws.Cells(firstY, IntX+3)+ws.Cells(firstY,IntX+5)-1` at some point makes `adder` a double.

Comment: Is it possible one of your cell values is not numeric?

Comment: In what way is this related to ibm-midrange or mainframe environments?

Comment: Try working each line by hand, step by step , and work one out until you find the variable that is doing something strange.  Integers must be whole numbers, so if for example, you have something creating a decimal? You no longer have an Integer you have a Double...